# displaying data from an array

Tags: php

I would like to extract the data from an array within an array and display it on a table. The problem is, when I use the function keys it seems it overwrites some of the data. The data should contain 135 rows but it only returns 114. I need to show all of them. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: Show your code, (sample)-input and desired (sample)-output.

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Answer (score 1):

difficult to say without looking at code but i would say that if you have duplicate keys with the same value, the new value overwrites the old one

Comment: Hi Sir. i'll try to get the code later. What you said was right sir, it overwrites the old one. What should I do about this sir?

Comment: as I said, difficult to suggest the best solution without looking at the code but how about adding a unique number with the key (have a variable i which is auto incremented)